# How to increase RabbitMQ sending/receiving speed

Tags: java, multithreading, rabbitmq

I have a project using RabbitMQ. It can receive 3000 messages per second in the best case. Here is my consumer code:

```
package com.mdnaRabbit.worker;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.QueueingConsumer;
import com.mdnaRabbit.worker.data.Data;
import org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils;

public class App {

    private static final String TASK_QUEUE_NAME = "task_queue";
    private static int i = 0;
    private static long timeStart;
    private static long timeFinish;
    private static long messPerSec;
    public static void main (String[] argv) throws IOException,InterruptedException{

        ExecutorService threader = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();

        factory.setHost("localhost");

        Connection connection = factory.newConnection(threader);
        final Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        channel.queueDeclare(TASK_QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
        System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");

        channel.basicQos(50);

        final QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
        channel.basicConsume(TASK_QUEUE_NAME, false, consumer);

        timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try {

            while (i<100000) {

                try {QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
                    Data mess = Data.fromBytes(delivery.getBody());

                    System.out.println(" [" + (i++) +"] Received " + mess.getHeader());

                    channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
                }catch (Exception e){
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        timeFinish = System.currentTimeMillis();
        messPerSec = Math.round ((i*1000)/(timeFinish - timeStart));

        System.out.println( "receives " + messPerSec + " per second");

        channel.close();
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

As you see I'm using ExecutorService to increase the speed and channel.basicQos(), but it doesn't help me much. Is there a way to increase receiving/sending speed(the sending speed increasing I think is the same with the receiving speed)

Comment: Get rid of the `println`. That's probably what's killing your performance.

Comment: It didn't help. I still receive 3000 messages per secont in case that I send 10000 messages. If I send 50000 messages I have receiving speed 1500 messages per second. To exclude any doubt, my PC is powerful enough(6-core processor and 16 Gb RAM)

Comment: have you had a look at this http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/04/17/rabbitmq-performance-measurements-part-1/ and this http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/04/25/rabbitmq-performance-measurements-part-2/

Comment: @NikitinMikhail: Did you still have a `println` on the other side? The sender can't send faster than the receiver receives, at least not for long. And the receiver can't receive faster than the sender sends.

Comment: no, I don't have println. sender sends messages to the queue from which consumer receives messages. nevertheless it can be 10000 messages in the queue, consumer's speed is not more than 2000-2500 messages per second.

Comment: well, robthewolf, I had look at this, there you can see that when persistence is true consumer can receive at least 4500 messages per second with consuming. In my case I don't execute any consumeng, but use persistence. and I have 3000 in the best case

Comment: I've tryed to make it in threads, using `ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)` and then calling `service.execute(new Runnable(){the rest code})` but it gives me only 100 messages per second. I thought I might use recommendations from [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html) about using threads in rabbit consumers and senders as you can see above. But this gives me 2500  messages per second only

Comment: It could be that your Data.fromBytes() is slow. Perhaps farm that out to a different thread

Comment: did you do any profiling?

Comment: it's very likely that Data.from bytes() is slow. Actually, I was told that such speed is absolutely normal for rabbitmq. I've found some ways to do increase speed: Using auto-acks or acknowledging larger batches of messages; Batching lots of messages together and sending them as a single message; use more than one queue.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used RabbitMQ before but I can share my experience from others messaging middleware. After all they face the same challenges.

By tuning you MQ server you can increase the number of messages per second but you have to give away some sort of funtionallity, e.g. guaranteed delivery. If you are using a single queue, the more threads you add, the more the contention on the queue lock.

What I have done in the past and managed to increase performance upto x300 times is to increase the message size, i.e. increase the work that can be done atomically by a single thread. I will try to describe my algorithm below (and would be grateful if someone knows a name for it).

1. Create a `threadLocal` collection that receives the messages
2. Provide (thread-safe) access to these collections by timer threads
3. Set a time and batch size limit
4. When you deliver a message, check if the size has reached the appropriate batch size. If it has, then flush the collection (i.e. package all the messages and send them in one go)
5. In order to satisfy the timing concerns, have a timer thread periodically check time elapsed from when the first message was delivered. If it exceeds your threashold the fluch the collection as above. (Don't forget to synchronize when flushing/checking)

(4). Not only you eliminate the network latency, you also eliminate the disk IO times as a normal HDD will take the same amount of time to write 1byte and approx 1.5MB.

`*` In my case this was more complicated because each delivering thread should be guaranteed. To support this you need to implement some sort of a `Barrier` so that delivering threads will block until an ACK is received by the master thread

`**` You might also like to implement a back-up strategy in case one message fails, which means that the whole batch will fail. I would suggest to send as individual messages if the batch fails.

`***` In other MQs there are various settings that might block your performance. These include throttling, limiting producer above a certain size of the queue, batching consumer messages, multiple levels of guarantee modes. (See below of a potential combination)

`****` A combination that might degrade performance is the following: A queue has a maximum size of 10MBs and the consumers pre-fetch 1000 msgs. For the sake of the example, let's say that each message has a size of 10K. This example will cause (in some MQs) a single consumer thread taking all the messages (even if you have 100 consumer threads). The producers on the other hand will be throttled and not allowed to add any more messages above the 10MB limit. The solutions here would be to increase the queue MaxSize and reduce the pre-fetch size. Monitoring/Profiling/Logging is always your friend here.

Hope this provides some better understanding of your problem. (BTW, 3000msgs/sec in persistent mode are not that bad.)